# Generating OpenAPI 3.0 spec for out of the box REST APIs in Production on Summer '23

Tags: openapispecification

I am working on using Open API 3.0 feature for rest web services and I don't see the option to enable in production.

Enabling the Beta
To enable this beta, follow these steps.

1. You must have either the Modify All Data or the Customize Application permission.
2. From Setup, in the Quick Find box, enter User Interface, and then select User Interface.
   On the User Interface page, select Enable Salesforce Platform REST API, OpenAPI 3.0 Spec Generation (Beta).

[Open API Salesforce URL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/openapi_beta.htm)

Does anyone worked on this previously? How do we request to enable this feature in production? I already sent an email to my org AE but as this is dreamforce week, I doubt to get any response from them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Their wires are a bit disconnected, yeah. This works in a Dev Ed org (Summer '23) or a full/partial/"real" sandbox on Winter '24. Does not work in Production org on Summer '23 - the option to flip it on is simply not there under User Interface settings. So likely a version difference and/or a safeguard of not having Beta features auto-available in Prod.

Comment: It means I have to look for other options to use the rest services. Is that correct? Also, does it work with when Salesforce upgrade the prod orgs with Winter'24?

Comment: Yes, you can use the platform standard (proprietary to SF) non-OAS interfaces: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/api_basics

Comment: Thank you. I will take the rest api approach then.